# What is the Purpose of Pydantic's SecretStr?

Tags: python, pydantic

I am learning the *Pydantic* module, trying to adopt its features/benefits via a toy [*FastAPI*](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) web backend as an example implementation.

I chose to use [Pydantic's `SecretStr`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#secret-types) to "hide" passwords. I know it is not really secure, and I am also using [`passlib`](https://passlib.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/lib/passlib.context.html?highlight=deprecated) for proper password encryption in DB storage (and using HTTPS for security in transit).

**But this got me thinking: if there is no real security to `SecretStr`, what is its purpose?**

I don't mean for this to sound inflammatory; Pydantic does not claim that the Secret Types are secure.  The only claim they provide is this:

> You can use the `SecretStr` and the `SecretBytes` data types for storing sensitive information that you do not want to be visible in logging or tracebacks.

But I do not understand this: how does `SecretStr` help in hiding logging or tracebacks?  Can't I just make sure not to log the password at all?

---

**Can someone provide an explanation + example to help me better understand** when and how it can be helpful?  I am struggling to find its real purpose... and if there is no benefit, then it is better to just use an `str` for the model/schema instead of `SecretStr`.

Comment: You can *try* to make sure not to log the password, but what if it gets passed around somewhere in a list or dictionary and logged as part of some other process? As it says, it's to prevent showing the value in logging or tracebacks by replacing the value with asterisks: https://github.com/samuelcolvin/pydantic/blob/e985857e5a9ede8d346b010a5a039aa84a089826/pydantic/types.py#L617-L618

Comment: Yeah, @jonrsharpe, I get how it works (but I do appreciate the GitHub link).

I just do not understand how this is helpful... if I have the wherewithal to make sure to use `SecretStr`, then I have the wherewithal to create unit tests that ensure the password is never being passed in any logs.  What am I missing here?

Comment: That you might not want to write a whole bunch of (probably highly coupled) unit tests that none of your code or any library code that you rely on ever logs that value; making sure that if they do it's not a problem is *much* more straightforward.

Comment: Good point, fair enough.  I think when I first stumbled upon `SecretStr` I was presuming it was far more powerful/cryptographically useful.  When I found out it wasn't, I was unable to "think outside the box" and figure out what its real purpose was.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You already answered a big part of the question yourself.

> You can use the SecretStr and the SecretBytes data types for storing
> sensitive information that you do not want to be visible in logging or
> tracebacks.

I would like to add another benefit.

Developers are constantly reminded that they are working with secrets because they need to invoke `.get_secret_value()` to read the real value.

We might consider this as **syntactic salt** (analog to syntactic sugar which makes things easier). Syntactic salt makes things harder to mess up. If you would try to send a SecretStr in a response model in e.g. FastAPI, you'd need to proactively enable that functionality.

From the [docs](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/types/#secret-types):

```py
class SimpleModelDumpable(BaseModel):
    password: SecretStr

    class Config:
        json_encoders = {
            SecretStr: lambda v: v.get_secret_value() if v else None
         }
```